# error when passing config file as argument to telnetd

Tags: macos, terminal

When I run the execute the below command on mac terminal. I m getting an error. I m not able to identify the reason.

```
/usr/local/sbin/telnetd --config /usr/local/etc/telnetd.conf
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/sbin/telnetd: illegal option -- -
```

It says, it is not the valid option for passing the .conf file as an option.

can anyone tell what is the right way to pass this file? I m following [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314240/502495) link.

Comment: Does the version of `telnetd` you have actually support `--config`? Check its man page.